# OpenGL convert original image to a red channel

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

The current IDE i used is visual studio 2010 .
saw a lot thread that use different SDL command to convert the image
but can't exactly get an idea to convert every pixel of the image to only red channel/ blue channel / green channel

Just trying to display only the red channel. isn't possible?

Code around 150 lines that i already did so far to display a image ( references : wiki and stackoverflow )

Link : http://codepad.org/oTA9RkV7

Can anyone teach and give some samples to show only red channel?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking and what your code is actually doing is two rather different things. You can use SDL to setup an openGL context, but you are not actually doing this in your code or using any openGL api-calls to do anything, you are only using SDL functions.

If you wish to blit the image onto the screen in RGB format I would be surprised if you do not have to convert the image yourself. I.e. Setting the green and blue channel to 0 yourself before blitting the image. Someone more familiar with SDL will be able to answer this better.

If, however, you wish to use openGL it is easier to implement the exact functionality you are requesting, but it is not the first thing you should attempt in openGL, I suggest [this tutorial](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html) as a starting point to learning OpenGL. In the description below I assume you are using a version of openGL that supports shaders. (i.e. GL 2+).

Before you can get to drawing each channel seperately, you will need to manage the following:

1. Draw a rectangle on the screen using `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`.
2. Load a texture using `glTexImage2D` and show it on your rectangle.

Now, you can show only the red channel using a fragment/pixel shader along the following lines.

```
#version 110
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(texture, texcoord).x, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: got any links that provide example so that i can study from it? tqtq

Comment: Yupp, the tutorial linked in the answer.

Comment: This code sets only one component of `gl_FragColor`, and leaves the remaining 3 components uninitialized. Undesired results are very likely when using this. The sequence of steps is also backwards. The texture needs to be loaded before making the draw calls.

Comment: @RetoKoradi The steps are not meant to be the calls in order, but rather my recommendation to which order to get things working. Regarding the unset components, I was wondering about that, I've fixed it now. Thx.